# Django use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have two models: `Comments` and `CommentFlags`

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     verbose_name=_('content type'),
                                     related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.CharField(_('object ID'), db_index=True, max_length=64)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), default=None, db_index=True)
    ...
    ...


class CommentFlags(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="comment_flags",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name="flags", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    ...
    ...
```

**CommentFlags** `flag` can have values: `like`, `dislike` etc.

**Problem Statement**: I want to get all `Comments` sorted by *number of likes* in *DESC* manner.

**Raw Query** for above problem statement:

```
SELECT 
    cmnts.*, coalesce(cmnt_flgs.num_like, 0) as num_like
FROM 
    comments cmnts
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        comment_id, Count(comment_id) AS num_like 
    FROM 
        comment_flags 
    WHERE 
        flag='like' 
    GROUP BY comment_id 
) cmnt_flgs      
ON 
    cmnt_flgs.comment_id = cmnts.id 
ORDER BY 
    num_like DESC
```

I have not been able to convert the above query in Django ORM Queryset.

What I have tried so far...

```
>>> qs = (Comment.objects.filter(flags__flag='like').values('flags__comment_id')
                         .annotate(num_likes=Count('flags__comment_id')))
```

which generates **different** query.

```
>>> print(qs.query)
>>> SELECT "comment_flags"."comment_id",
       COUNT("comment_flags"."comment_id") AS "num_likes"
    FROM "comments"
    INNER JOIN "comment_flags"
    ON ("comments"."id" = "comment_flags"."comment_id")
    WHERE "comment_flags"."flag" = 'like'
    GROUP BY "comment_flags"."comment_id",
             "comments"."submit_date"
   ORDER BY "comments"."submit_date" ASC
   LIMIT 21
```

Problem with above ORM queryset is, it uses **InnerJoin** and also I don't know how it adds **submit_date** in **groupby** clause.

Can you please suggest me a way to convert above mentioned Raw query to Django ORM queryset ?

Comment: Did you try using [raw sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)?

Comment: Obviously I am aware about raw queries ,but As I have mentioned  I want the above problem statement to be done using Orm Queryset type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `filter` argument in `Count`:

```
qs = (Comment.objects.all()
      .annotate(num_likes=Count('flags__comment_id', filter=Q(flags__flag='like'))))
```

It may produce slightly different query that you're expecting, depending on the database backend, but it should have equivalent behavior.

Comment: Ah..I missed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) part in django docs. Anyhow thanks ! for introducing me to Postgres Filter Clause ! :)